# How to get array of objects from a excel sheet's cell in java using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I have to import an excel sheet in mysql db, the excel sheet contains a cell which is in the format of Array of json, I am not able to read that cell using apache poi's getStringCellValue method, is there any way I can read that cell's data and store it in DB as it is.

[sample of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uatiY.jpg)

```
Integer price = row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue(); 
String name = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue(); 
String value =row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
```

here I want value to give me the exact array of json in string format , but It is not givving exact json array , instead gives just 20 Gb .

How can i read json array in an excel sheet in java using apache-poi or any other lib.

Comment: Twenty [gigabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte)?! Why not export the [tag:json] to a flat file where you can import it into the DB? Your DB may include import support.

Comment: how to export json to flat file, i am not able to read the values of the json.

Comment: I don't know what's current; maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/get-table-data).